# Should I use a Critical Section or a memory barrier when setting a shared variable?

Tags: c, multithreading, winapi

Say I have the following code:

```
/* Global Variables */

int flag = 0;
int number1;
int number2;

//------------------------------------

/* Thread A */

number1 = 12345;
number2 = 678910;
flag = 1;

//------------------------------------

/* Thread B */

while (flag == 0) {}
printf("%d", number1);
printf("%d", number2);
```

In **Thread A**, the code may not be executed in order, it may be executed for example like this:

```
/* Thread A */

flag = 1;
number1 = 12345;
number2 = 678910;
```

To prevent this, I should use a memory barrier.

But I am not sure if I should use a regular memory barrier, for example:

```
/* Thread A */

number1 = 12345;
number2 = 678910;
MEMORY_BARRIER_GOES_HERE
flag = 1;
```

Or if I should use a Critical Section, for example:

```
/* Thread A */

number1 = 12345;
number2 = 678910;
EnterCriticalSection(&cs);
flag = 1;
LeaveCriticalSection(&cs);
```

Comment: If you use type `atomic_int` for `flag`, you're all set

Comment: "*In Thread A, the code may not be executed in order*" Why?

Comment: @alk Doesn't the CPU reorder instructions?

Comment: Might be, but from the C language perspective this is not an issue. And if it is, then it is to be taken care of by the compiler developers.

Comment: *Doesn't the CPU reorder instructions* - yes, or execute instructions *asynchronous*

Comment: @alk - *Might be, but from the C language perspective this is not an issue. And if it is, then it is to be taken care of by the compiler developers* - this is absolute false

Comment: @RbMm: You might want to read about the concept of "Sequence Points".

Comment: @alk - and so what ? when we plain write `x = a; y = b;` as is nothing prevent even compiler from reordering here. cpu reordering (on some platform) at all separate question.

Comment: @RbMm: [From the C11 Standard](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.1.2.3p3): "*The presence of a sequence point between the evaluation of expressions A and B implies that every value computation and side effect associated with A is sequenced before every value computation and side effect associated with B.*"

Comment: @alk - and where you view sequence point in `number1 = 12345;
number2 = 678910;
flag = 1;` ? concrete here where ?

Comment: @RbMm: The semicolons introduce Sequence Points.

Comment: @alk - here no. call external functions for example - yes. but simply `;` - absolute no

Comment: @RbMm: http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#C "*Between the evaluation of a full expression and the next full expression to be evaluated.*"

Comment: @alk - what you say this is nonsense. on some cpu platform read and writes on memory can be reordered. even on x86-x64 - read can be reordered before write. so if we (compiler) write `x = r1; r2 = y` - processor can execute this in order `r2 = y; x = r1` (`r` - registers) - are compiler need insert processor memory barrier  between every instructions for read/write ? again this nonsense. programmer must care about this if it actually need

Comment: @alk The Sequence Points concept has to do with the ordering of a single statement and evaluation of side-effects (for example: `x++ || y < x` has `||` as sequence point ensuring the side-effect of `x++` is applied before evaluating `y < x`).  The compiler and CPU are free to reorder statements that have no effect on each other, such as `x+=5; y=2;` because the order of their execution has no bearing on that process of execution; in the end, x will be incremented by 5, and y will equal 2 regardless of the order of operations.

Comment: @ChristianGibbons: I am completely aware of this. The moment I understood this was a misunderstanding I stopped arguing.

Comment: @LWimsey (re: using std::atomic) You can't just use a simple assignment though, see: [here](https://godbolt.org/g/9PimHD)  (note no `MFENCE` instruction generated, nor, according to [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic), is there any promise that there will be - "accesses to atomic objects **may** ... order non-atomic memory accesses").  RbMm has told us how to do it right, if you want to use std::atomic.  Be careful out there people.

Comment: @PaulSanders Memory Ordering is a fundamental property of std::atomic operations and, without any ordering parameter specified, the operations are seq/cst by default.
The generated assembly (on Goldbolt) contains `xchg` instructions; Those are used as a replacement for `MOV/MFENCE`.
According to the Intel manual, if a memory operand is referenced by `XCHG`, the `LOCK` prefix is implied (which flushes the store buffer, just like `MFENCE` does)..

Comment: @PaulSanders I think the reason cppreference uses the phrase '_may .. order .. memory accesses_' is because it only enforces ordering with certain ordering parameters (ie. not with 'relaxed`).
In the code included by the OP, the default seq/cst operations guarantee that the store to `flag` synchronizes-with the load from `flag` and therefore the numbers in thread B are guaranteed to contain the values stored by thread A.

Comment: @LWimsey Yes, you're right on all counts, I forgot about that implied LOCK.  And if you chase `std::atomic::operator=` down to the equivalent call to `store`, you end up where you say you do.  I guess it makes sense.  `operator=` (and `operator T`) would not be of much use otherwise.  Just forget I said anything in the first place :)

Answer (score 4):

Trying to be clever with a lockless threading model (barriers, atomics, interlocked ops, etc...) to protect more than a single variable instead of standard locking mechanism is only going to lead to bugs.

You need to protect all the variables (`number1`, `number2`, and `flag`) with a lock (Critical Section)

Thread A:

```
EnterCriticalSection(&cs);
    flag = 1;
    number1 = 12345;
    number2 = 678910;
LeaveCriticalSection(&cs);
```

Thread B:

```
while (1)
{
    int n1, n2;

    EnterCriticalSection(&cs);
    if (flag)
    {
        n1 = number1;
        n2 = number2;
        break;
    }
    LeaveCriticalSection(&cs);
}
printf("%d", n1);
printf("%d", n2);
```

Also, on Windows, you can avoid that entire `while (flag == 0) {}` loop from burning a CPU core with a [Conditional Variable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682052(v=vs.85).aspx). Switching from a continuous polling mechanism to a notification based mechanism will generate far better performance results than trying to do tricky interlocked operations.

**Better:**

Thread A:

```
EnterCriticalSection(&cs);
    flag = 1;
    number1 = 12345;
    number2 = 678910;
LeaveCriticalSection(&cs);
WakeAllConditionVariable(&conditional_variable);
```

Thread B:

```
EnterCriticalSection(&cs);

while (flag == 0)
{
    // This will atomically Leave the CS and block until the conditional_variable is fired by the other thread

    SleepConditionVariableCS(&conditional_variable, &cs, INFINITE);

    // After it returns, it will re-enter the CS.
}

n1 = number1;
n2 = number2;
LeaveCriticalSection(&cs);
printf("%d", n1);
printf("%d", n2);
```

Comment: *"You need to protect all the variables (number1, number2, and flag) with a lock (Critical Section)"* Why do I need to do that? based on what I have learnt so far about memory barriers, I only need to enclose `flag = 1` in a critical section.

Comment: @James - you not need enclose flag = 1 in a critical section. you need set `flag = 1` with release semantic and read `flag` with acquire semantic. you need exactly [Release-Acquire ordering](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order#Release-Acquire_ordering) here

Comment: James, while you **might be correct**, if the code path or threading models changes (e.g. another thread introduced, code path of thread A is executed multiple times, or values can change multiple times), then everything falls apart when using a lockless threading model. The perf gains of trying to be lockless are near-zero unless you doing something highly specialized. The cost of fixing bugs wrt to threads and locks are very expensive.

Answer (score 1):

in your concrete example you need exactly [*Release-Acquire ordering*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order#Release-Acquire_ordering)

```
int number1, number2, flag = 0;

/* Thread A */

number1 = 12345;
number2 = 678910;
//--------------
atomic_store_explicit(&flag, 1, memory_order_release);


/* Thread B */
if (atomic_load_explicit(&flag, memory_order_acquire) != 0)
{
    //--------------
    printf("%d", number1);
    printf("%d", number2);
}
```

> If an atomic store in thread *A* is tagged `memory_order_release` and
>   an atomic load in thread *B* from the same variable (`flag`) is tagged
>   `memory_order_acquire`, all memory writes (non-atomic and relaxed
>   atomic) that happened-before the atomic store from the point of view
>   of thread A, become visible side-effects in thread B, that is, once
>   the atomic load is completed, thread B is guaranteed to see everything
>   (`number1, number2`) thread A wrote to memory.

also you can define flag as `volatile int flag` and use [`/volatile:ms`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj204392.aspx) *CL.exe* option:

```
int number1, number2;
volatile int flag = 0;

/* Thread A */

number1 = 12345;
number2 = 678910;
//--------------
flag = 1;


/* Thread B */
if (flag)
{
    //--------------
    printf("%d", number1);
    printf("%d", number2);
}
```

> **/volatile:ms**
>
> Selects Microsoft extended volatile semantics, which add memory ordering guarantees beyond the ISO-standard C++ language.
>   Acquire/release semantics are guaranteed on volatile accesses.
>   However, this option also forces the compiler to generate hardware
>   memory barriers, which might add significant overhead on ARM and other
>   weak memory-ordering architectures. If the compiler targets any
>   platform except ARM, this is default interpretation of volatile.

but anyway `while (flag == 0) ;` is not a good solution (spinlock). here can be used set/wait on event, conditional variables, send/post message to concrete thread or iocp. depend from concrete task

Comment: This question is tagged as `C`, not `C++`

Comment: Mind translating this into C? This is a C question.

Comment: Also you seem to be ignoring this referring to Thread A: "*the code may not be executed in order*"

Comment: @alk - the memory barrier (here release-acquire) exactly design for solve "the code may not be executed in order"

Comment: Please have 2nd closer look at the question. Especially at the snippet after "*it may be executed for example like this:*".

Comment: @alk - *the code may not be executed in order, it may be executed for example like this:* and so what ? OP mean compiler and processor reordering. for this and exist compiler and processor barrier for prevent this. or what you mean ?

Comment: "*OP mean compiler and processor reordering*" from what do you deduce this?

Comment: @alk - *the code may not be executed in order* - ok, how you can understand this ? what else can cause code not execute in program write order ?

Comment: Thread A: `if (some random decision) { number1 = 12345;
number2 = 678910;
flag = 1; } else { flag = 1; number1 = 12345;
number2 = 678910; }`

Comment: @alk - write such code is no sense. i absolute sure that OP mean compile and processor reordering.

Comment: @RbMm Yes, I mean reordering during compilation and during CPU execution.

Comment: @James - for prevent compile reordering enough [`_ReadWriteBarrier`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f20w0x5e.aspx) for example. for processor reordering can be need something more. if you target x86-x64 - not need do something here. but for say arm - need special cpu instruction. `atomic_store_explicit` and `atomic_load_explicit` do this auto for you, depend from cpu target

Answer (score 0):

If you declare your flag as a `volatile LONG` then you can do:

`InterlockedExchange (&flag, 1);`

This generates a full memory barrier, see [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683590(v=vs.85).aspx).  Given that this is tagged as a C question, this seems a good way to do it.

In real time code (e.g. low-latency audio processing) using a CRITICAL_SECTION can lead to [priority inversion](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_inversion) if a lower priority thread ever claims it.  I doubt if that is an issue here, but I have had this happen to me.

Comment: You need to be careful with this.  The `volatile` semantics necessary to make this work are effectively Microsoft-specific.

Comment: @AndrewHenle Yes, I took that as a given, from the `winapi` tag.